# Android Studio Kotlin error: 'class kotlin.Result$Failure cannot be cast to class java.lang.String'

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Android Studio keeps giving me some error:
"java.lang.ClassCastException: class kotlin.Result$Failure cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (kotlin.Result$Failure is in unnamed module of loader com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader @6f695d81; java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')"

Due to the error a huge part of Kotlin code is underlined red with this comment: [image: Screenshot]

I've already tried restarting IDE, reopening project and invalidating caches, it didn't work. What do I do?

Comment: Can you, please, add the actual code to the question?

Comment: I think that the error occurs not because of the code, but of the IDE. The error is shown in all the Kotlin files.

Comment: Just to check, have you tried to create a new empty project?

Comment: @AlexanderDadukin, my other projects work fine. The error occurred after I stopped gradle build for emulator.

Comment: I had the same error when starting Android Studio. Deleting folder .idea in project and restarting Android Studio helped me. 
Also after this I went to Run > Edit Configurations and set launch to a Default Activity (this step is specific for my project, I think this setting was removed when I deleted .idea folder).

Comment: @Maxim , thanks, but I've already solved (?) the problem. Just cloned the last version of the project from GitHub